# Piecewise function: Find equation and solve it using data points

Tags: python, math, numpy

I have several points. Because sometimes 1 or 2 of them may be unknown (both x and y coordinates), I'd like to find the equation and be able to find those missing points, if possible by numpy. 
Simplified model:

```
a = np.arange(12)
x = np.array([1000,1010,1020,1030,1040,1050,1060,1070,1080,1090,1100,1110])
y = np.array([0,50,100,250,300,350,500,550,600,750,800,850])
```

which looks like:

```
[[   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11]
[1000 1010 1020 1030 1040 1050 1060 1070 1080 1090 1100 1110]
 [   0   50  100  250  300  350  500  550  600  750  800  850]]
```

As you can see, the x increase 10 by 10, the y increase by 50, then 50, then 150, and so on.
I tried solving the problem with least squares but it's not satisfying:

```
A = np.array([ x, np.ones(12)])
m,c = np.linalg.lstsq(A.T,y)[0]
sol = m*x + c
print sol.astype(int)
```

This returns: `[-23  58 139 221 302 384 465 547 628 710 791 873]`
Questions: how to proceed, preferably using numpy,  to get results closer to the data points ? Thanks 
Dominique

Comment: Do the `least square` for sub-groups of your array list! I think that would help!

Comment: I gave an answer, but I have an impression that isn't really what you are trying to do. Are you trying to say that the data is missing at y values of 150, 200, 400, 450, 650, 700, etc., and you want to first fit the linear relation to the rest of the data and then impute the missing values using the fit model? The way the example data of (x, y) pairs is given, it is not really clear what you want out of this.

Comment: Here, no data is missing. But I want to be able to recompute if one is missing, say x[9] and y[9]. In that case, the least squares gives me y=710 although I'd like the result to be around 740-760.

Comment: Does that mean you *exactly* know the form of your function from which you can recover y given x? The data is not noisy to begin with, so if you knew the exact form of function f(x), then it would be better to simply compute f(x). You can just create f(x) that reproduces the data exactly.

Comment: Yes Constantine, I know but it's what I wanted to avoid ...Thanks.

Comment: Taro Sato, I agree. Thank you. Already done but with the data I get, it's not always easy. Sometimes, 1 data is missing. Sometimes 2, sometimes 2 in a row... The gap between the points and the group of points may vary as well... Anyway, for the moment, I'll use my "guess" method (identifying gaps, their values, rebuild an array by testing where to include the missing values,... Thanks for all

Comment: @Dominique I updated my answer with interpolation. Is that closer to what you wanted? Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure on what basis you are saying the results are not closer to the data points. When I plot them up, they look fine to me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d


x = np.array([1000, 1010, 1020, 1030, 1040, 1050,
              1060, 1070, 1080, 1090, 1100, 1110])
y = np.array([0, 50, 100, 250, 300, 350,
              500, 550, 600, 750, 800, 850])

A = np.vstack([ x, np.ones(12)])
m, c = np.linalg.lstsq(A.T, y)[0]
sol = m*x + c

finterp = interp1d(x, y)

print x[9], finterp(x[9]), y[9]

plt.plot(x, y, 'o', label='data')
plt.plot(x, sol, '-.', label='fit')
plt.plot(x, finterp(x), '-', label='interpolated')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Based on the comments, I have added interpolation. I am not really fond of this approach (I prefer defining function if it's already known) as when the data is noise you might end up overfitting, but it seems like interpolation is closer to what you want.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I agree but I should have written "not **enough** satisfying" ! I need deviations to be smaller than these (less than 10 would be fine). '(y-sol).astype(int)' returns 'array([ 23,  -8, -39,  28,  -2, -34,  34,   2, -28,  39,   8, -23])'. I'm looking for closer results. If possible...

Comment: By construction, the least squares method tries to minimize the deviations, so I don't think you can do better than this, unless you use a little more complicated model. Upon reflection I think it's not clear from your original question that what you are trying to do. Now, I don't understand what values you consider missing in your example.

Comment: +1 - this is a nice answer, and the comment suggests that you're the only person in this thread that has any idea of what's going on.